# Php array_filter with custom class to filter array with timestamp

Tags: php

in my web app i have some array which that return array like with this output:

```
[
    0=>
        pk = "ID"
        username = "PAGE"
        full_name = "PAGE"
        is_private = false
        reel_auto_archive = "on"
        latest_reel_media = "1536080134"
        is_favorite = false
    1=>
        pk = "ID"
        username = "PAGE"
        full_name = "PAGE"
        is_private = false
        reel_auto_archive = "on"
        latest_reel_media = "1536050134"
        is_favorite = false
]
```

in that i want to use array_filter for filtering array with `latest_reel_media` that's is timestamp when that's lower than for example `1535707694`

for example:

```
$mediaTime = 86400 * 3;
$time_limit = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - $mediaTime;
$followers = array_filter($followers, [new LowerThanFilter($time_limit,'latest_reel_media'), "isLower"]);
```

`LowerThanFilter` class:

```
class LowerThanFilter
{
    private $limit;
    private $latest_reel_media;
    function __construct($limit,$latest_reel_media)
    {
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->latest_reel_media=$latest_reel_media;
    }
    function isLower($i)
    {
        return $i <= $this->limit;
    }
}
```

after testing code for more than 100000 record, `array_fillter` don't work and return all of `100000` record which that is not correct

Comment: How does your class compare the `latest_reel_media` key to the `$limit` property ?

Comment: @AymDev yes you are right, how can i add that to compare?

Comment: why not use http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: `array_filter` passes *elements* to the filtering function. In your case it means your filtering function gets *whole* record in `$i` parameter. So you need something like this: `return $i['latest_reel_media'] <= $this->limit;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must compare with the `latest_reel_media` key. Therefore, using your class, you should set it as a property (so your class is reusable).

```
class LowerThanFilter
{
    private $limit;

    // $key is an optional parameter
    function __construct($limit, ?string $key = null)
    {
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->key   = $key;
    }

    // Thanks @weirdan for the use of __invoke()
    function __invoke($i)
    {
        // if $key is set, compare with key
        if (!is_null($this->key)) {
            return $i->{$this->key} <= $this->limit;
        }
        return $i <= $this->limit;
    }
}
```

And filter like:

```
$followers = array_filter($followers, new LowerThanFilter($time_limit, 'latest_reel_media'));
```

---

Another solution would be using an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with inheritance (`use ($var)`) (not reusable but worth giving a look):

```
// this can easily stand on a single line too
$followers = array_filter($followers, function($i) use ($time_limit) {
    return $i['latest_reel_media'] <= $time_limit;
});
```

Comment: i get `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` error for both of solutions

Comment: For the class variant it may make sense to rename `isLower` to `__invoke`. Then you can pass the object as it it was a function itself: https://ideone.com/JYLUpl

Comment: «*Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*» — then your entries must be object rather than arrays (which you didn't really specify in the question). `return $i->{$this->key} <= $this->limit;` should be enough to fix it.

Comment: I don't get your last comment ? I'm editing my answer, your idea is great !

Comment: @AymDev array data is `stdClass`, for example first row of `$followers` is `0 = {stdClass} [11]  pk = "ID"` and i get error again

Comment: @weirdan Thanks, you are right, `return $i->{$this->key} <= $this->limit;` resolve my problem

Comment: Oh sorry, I couldn't see @DolDurma 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

Only replace your return statement in isLower function to this and it will work fine:

return $i['latest_reel_media'] <= $this->limit;